# CKEDITOR On element append

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I can't seem to find an event in the documentation that will trigger when a specific element has been inserted into the HTML of a textarea.
For example if the user makes text bold, I would like to trigger an event when the 'b' tag is added into the HTML; as well as any other tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change` event and check if `b` is present in input:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline(element, {
    resize_enabled: false,
    skin: 'rich-text,' + RX_RICH_TEXT.ckeditor.skinPath,
    on: {
        change: function () {
            var dom = this.getData();
            if (dom.includes('<b>')) {
                // your logic
            }
        },
```

Comment: Wouldn't the change event fire every time a key is pressed? Seems inefficient.

Comment: this is event is fired when DOM inside CKEDITOR element is updated